# If Jsoup works with android?

Tags: android, jsoup

I need to parse data from web in my Android Application.Among many solutions i find Jsoup is simpler and straight forward.But i can't use it in my application.If anybody shares the idea it will be great
thanks

Comment: I can't import jsoup class.Error occured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right Click on project > BuildPath> Add External Archives > select the .jar file :)

Answer (score 0):

Just put it in the `libs` directory, make a right click on `gson-1.6.jar`, select `Build Path > Add to Build Path` and it should just works :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding jsoup to my libs dir did not work for me.  Instead I extracted the jsoup source and then added it to my src directory of my android project.  Then on next compile it compiled and converted all code to DEX.  Upon inspection of the APK the jsoup libary was indeed there.  Finally, I tested and it worked great!