# Android JSoup not working

Tags: android, jsoup

I want to extract information from the web and show that value in my Android app. When I try to write the following code, nothing gets initialized to my textView. I can't see the data I wanted. Can you please tell me whats wrong?

**EDIT**: Android is now not even going past the line:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://movies.ign.com/articles/100/1002569p1.html").get();
```

When I run the emulator, it just exits the App. Why is this happening??

Here is my code:

```
public class Search extends Activity {

  private static final String TAG = "TVGuide";

  String outputtext;
  Parser parser;

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search);
    TextView outputTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputTextView);
    String id = "main-article-content";
    try {
      Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://movies.ign.com/articles/100/1002569p1.html").get();
      Elements elementsHtml = doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("id", "main-article-content");
      for (Element element : elementsHtml) {
        Log.i("PARSED ELEMENTS:", URLDecoder.decode(element.text(), HTTP.UTF_8));
        outputTextView.setText(element.text());
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you imported the class *org.w3c.dom.Document*  instead of the required one, **org.jsoup.nodes.Document** by mistake.

Comment: @bertantk Yes I fixed that. thanks a lot. Can you please help me figure out why I am not getting anything set to the textView? I can't see any text

Comment: element.text(); returns nothing, so i think the problem is related to what you use for parsing what you want to extract from the page..

Comment: I also have had problems using JSoup on Android. See 2nd answer though : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219188/if-jsoup-works-with-android

Answer (score 0):

> EDIT: Android is now not even going past the line:

Jsoup cant connect to the site? Try to add timeout on the connect:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://movies.ign.com/articles/100/1002569p1.html").timeout(10000).get();
```